# how to check firebase firestore user data collection is empty

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a note app and I have a problem. It is how to check if Firebase Firestore user data collection is empty.

````
  Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("mNotes").document(firebaseUser.getUid()).collection("userNotes").orderBy("title", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);



        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<firebasemodel> allusernotes = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<firebasemodel>().setQuery(query, firebasemodel.class).build(); ```


this code is used to get data from Firestore.
how can I check user data collection is empty with the if statement.
I am a beginner.
````

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** 2023-03-30

Nowadays, the simplest option that we have is to use [Query#count()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#count()), which:

> Counts the documents in the result set of this query without actually downloading the documents.

So if the above method return `0`, it means that the collection is empty, otherwise, it will contain a number of documents that is equal to the number the above method returns.

---

> How to check if Firebase Firestore user data collection is empty?

Firestore doesn't have the concept of an empty collection. If a collection doesn't contain any documents, it doesn't exist at all. So there is no API that can help you check if a collection actually exists. A collection in Firestore will start to exist if there is at least one document present in it.

So to solve this, you might consider checking the number of documents within the collection or subcollection like this:

```
val db = Firebase.firestore
val usersRef = db.collection("users")
usersRef.get().addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        val numberOfDocs = it.result.documents.size
        if (numberOfDocs > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG,"users collection already exists!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Janith. Hey. Can I help you with other information?